# How can I add a custom arrow using python docx or python pptx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx, python-pptx

I need to add arrows like this on my document or powerpoint. How can I do this? Do you recommend an image or is there a way to add custom arrows?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be to find characters that look like that.

For example, this search was helpful: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/geometric_shapes/list.htm

Edit: I just tried pasting U+25BC from that page into a new Powerpoint slide (in the title field) and got a down arrow (▼). I'm pretty confident that can be made to work in python-pptx.

Comment: I think Martin's is exactly the right approach and is what I would do. The alternatives would be to use an image or native PowerPoint shape, but those would both have to be separate shapes so wouldn't move together with the text or automatically align themselves. If you used characters and right-aligned the text, the up/down arrows would align in a column, if that were important.